# Выровнять карточки по высоте

Tags: bootstrap4

Делаю карточки товаров с помощью Bootstrap 4. Нужно, чтобы в строке располагалось от 4х до 1й карточки, в зависимости от размера окна девайса.
Как нужно поправить код и какие применить стили, чтобы карточки были одинаковой высоты?

https://codepen.io/KateGN/pen/rrvMrb

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px200/" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px200/" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px200/" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px200/" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px200/" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы выровнять элементы по высоте можно использовать классы `h-*`

Например добавьте к вашим карточкам `class = "card h-100"`